# Implementing a method that returns two numbers

Tags: objective-c

How can I implement a method that returns two numbers? Something like:

```
-(float[2])returnTwoFloatsUsingNumber:(float)aNumber;
```

Comment: And what this function should do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a struct that contains two float fields. Or cheat and use a preexisting struct like `CGPoint`.

Comment: Whoa i could never think of such a cheat. Thats great.